# Ignite thick client can not create snapshot unless it configures DataStorageConfiguration as persistent

Tags: ignite

I am using ignite 2.11.0. I have a cluster with two nodes. Both use native persistence. I coded a simple thick client that connects to this cluster and I would like to trigger a snapshot from my code. However if i do like this

```
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

//DataStorageConfiguration dataStorageConfiguration = new DataStorageConfiguration();
//DataRegionConfiguration defaultDataRegionConfiguration = dataStorageConfiguration.getDefaultDataRegionConfiguration();
//defaultDataRegionConfiguration.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
//
//cfg.setDataStorageConfiguration(dataStorageConfiguration);

cfg.setClientMode(true);

// Setting up an IP Finder to ensure the client can locate the servers.
TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
ipFinder.setAddresses(Collections.singletonList("127.0.0.1:47500..47509"));
cfg.setDiscoverySpi(new TcpDiscoverySpi().setIpFinder(ipFinder));

// Starting the node
Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);
IgniteSnapshot snapshot = ignite.snapshot();
IgniteFuture<Void> future = snapshot.createSnapshot("mysnapshot");
future.get();
```

I get

**"SEVERE: Cluster-wide snapshot operation failed:
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Create snapshot request has been rejected. Snapshots on an in-memory clusters are not allowed"**

If I **uncomment** the getDefaultDataRegionConfiguration section. I can take a snapshot. I do not understand why my thick client needs persistence.

Answer (score 0):

The thick client doesn't take the snapshot itself, rather it sends a request to the server nodes asking for a snapshot to be taken. A Snapshot requires that persistence be enabled in the cluster. The function [snapshot.createSnapshot("mysnapshot")](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/ea52fa4719ffff0f330c98c83347aa6e5547ac9b/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/internal/processors/cache/persistence/snapshot/IgniteSnapshotManager.java#L1245) does a [check on the local config](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/ea52fa4719ffff0f330c98c83347aa6e5547ac9b/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/internal/processors/cache/persistence/snapshot/IgniteSnapshotManager.java#L1255) to make sure that persistence is enabled, thus the error.

Comment: The native persistence is active on both nodes. As i said if i uncomment the  DataRegionConfiguration code everything works. So the problem is on my thick client side and i don't understand why my client needs this code.

Comment: Rather what i am trying to ask my thick client does not store data on itself because i am calling setClientMode(true) but i need to activate persistence on my client. Why?

Comment: As it is now coded, follow the link, the client does check the local config for persistence. The design question, as to why it does this, is beyond the scope of this question.